# SSIS - SQL statement written to text file

Tags: ssis

I am relatively new to SSIS.  I have created an SSIS package that contains many control flows (5).  The control flows each contain a data flow, which writes to  flat files (1 for each, so there are 5 in total).  The process works well, however I have noticed that for one of the data flows also writes the SQL statement i.e. the flat file looks like this:

```
    SELECT id,name FROM Names 
    id,name 
    1,Ian 
    2,Craig
    3,Sarah
```

Why is the SQL statement written to the text file i.e. line 1 of the above should not be written to the text file.  Is there a setting somewhere?

Comment: To clarify, the initial row is what is at fault? The rest of the file looks good?

Comment: @billinkc, yes.  I resolved this problem by recreating the data flow.  I am intrigued to know what caused the problem though.